Is there a physical description of Mrs. Barrymore?
In the novel, The Hound of the Baskervilles, Mr. and Mrs. Barrymore are the servants at Baskerville Hall.  The novel gives a physical description of Mr. Barrymore; however, I do not recall if there is a physical description of Mrs. Barrymore in the novel.
I have seen probably every film and television adaptation of this novel.  Mrs. Barrymore has varying physical appearances in these adaptations, which is making me question if the novel gives a physical description of her.  In some adaptations, she's tall, thin and has the appearance of a younger woman (25-30 years old).  In other adaptations, she's short, stout and has the appearance of an older woman (35-45 years old).
Does the novel provide a physical description of Mrs. Barrymore?

These novels are no longer under copyright and can be viewed at Gutenberg.

Yes, Watson gives us three brief physical descriptions of the character:

It chanced that after breakfast I met Mrs. Barrymore in the long corridor with the sun full upon her face. She was a large, impassive, heavy-featured woman with a stern set expression of mouth. [Chapter 7]
Mrs. Barrymore is of interest to me. She is a heavy, solid person, very limited, intensely respectable, and inclined to be puritanical. [Chapter 8]
It was a woman’s voice, and Mrs. Barrymore, paler and more horror-struck than her husband, was standing at the door. Her bulky figure in a shawl and skirt might have been comic were it not for the intensity of feeling upon her face. [Chapter 9]
Arthur Conan Doyle (1902). The Hound of the Baskervilles. Project Gutenberg.

